# SwiftUI - Add two gestures to a view?

Tags: swiftui

I want to add two gesture recongnisers to a view, but I'm unsure how to do it!  I've tried the below, but only the first one fires (whatever order they are in).

```
            .gesture(
            TapGesture(count: 2)
                .onEnded { _ in
                     print("Double Tap!")
                }
        )
        .gesture(
            LongPressGesture()
                .onEnded { _ in
                    print("Long Press!")
            }
        )
```

I thing I need to use simultaneousGesture, but I'm unsure of the syntax.  I've tried:

```
.simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded({self.showAddEditToDoView.toggle()}), TapGesture().onEnded({print("Double Tap!")}))
```

But that produces:

```
Missing argument label 'including:' in call
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
.simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded({ _ in 
   self.showAddEditToDoView.toggle()
}))
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded({
   print("Double Tap!")
}))
```

Comment: Order matters! Using inverse order I had some issues.